# purecss make .pure-menu-scrollable and pure-menu-has-children work together

Tags: html, css, web, yui-pure-css

Actually I would like to have horizontally scrollable menu with dropdowns smth like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">

<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-scrollable pure-menu-fixed">
    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading">Brand</a>
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Log Out</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link" name="menuLink1">Contact</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Email</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tumblr Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it does not work. Actually horizontal menu scrolling works, but dropdown does not(( I found out that it is because .pure-menu-scrollable and pure-menu-has-children classes can't get along. So at this point I can have or scrolling menu or menu with dropdown but not both at the same time.

Is there any way to make pure menu both scrollable and with dropdown?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655078/purecss-scrollable-horizontal-menu-z-index-issue

Comment: thanks)) hovever I've already understood my mistake >> in official pure docs here http://purecss.io/menus/#scrollable-horizontal-menu there is a notice, that scroll menus cant be used along with dropdowns(((

by the way it is a very long time since pure was updated last time(( so I think it is not the best choice now(( Also to say now I know css/html much better and I do prefer writing from scratch without any framework (maybe normalize.css only)

Comment: Yes, shortly after I posted this I ended up coming to the same conclusion as you about pure. I reimplemented the menus to behave how I wanted and it was much easier than I expected.